# Is it possible to use Google Charts with $refs? (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a timeline chart using Google Charts. The chart is present in a dedicated component, which I then call from a parent component. However, the drawchart function requires the getElementByID response, which is always null in the case of Vue. Is there a way to render the chart using ref?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can access using a "ref" instead a `getElementByID`:

```html
<div><GChart ref="chart" type="TimeLine" :options="options" :data="chartData" /></div>
```

Inside your function into the `methods(){}` you can use this:

```js
this.$refs.chart.chartObject;
```

Also if you want to generate a dynamic Chart you can push the elements into chartData inside the same function into `methods(){}`